# pymysql cursor doesn't close

Tags: python, pymysql

In the PyMySQL library, in cursors.py the following functions are called:

```
def __enter__(self):
  return self

def __exit__(self, *exc_info):
  del exc_info
  self.close()
```

That's mean that if I use the cursor class in the `with` statement, the cursor should close whenever I go out from the nested block. Why instead it remain setted?

```
db = pymysql.connect(config)

with pymysql.cursors.Cursor(db) as cursor:
    print(cursor)

print(cursor)
```

also:

```
db = pymysql.connect(config)

with db.cursor() as cursor:
    print(cursor)

print(cursor)
```

both forms return the cursor object printing two times (one time inside the `with` statement and one time out from the `with` statement?. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closing a cursor doesn't null out the cursor, just detaches it from the database. Try printing cursor.connection instead.

Also, I think you're expecting the "with" keyword to delete the object in question, but it's really just syntactic sugar around the enter and exit functions.